# When I set the rowHeight for UITableView, shouldn't the height of cell changed as well?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

Question:
**When I set the `rowHeight` for `UITableView`, shouldn't the height of cell changed as well?**
Here is the situation that leads me to think about it:

---

I want to set a separate line for each table view cell at bottom, what's more, I want to set the row height for it from `44` to `32`. The result I want is like below:
[image]

Row height setting is done correctly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView setRowHeight:32.0f];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    //...
}

// Even use the delegate of UITableView
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 32.0f;
}
```

However, when I was adding separate line for cell, I met a issue: I want to set the separate line at bottom of the cell, so I set the `y` position by `cell.frame.size.height - 1.0f`. Unfortunately, the result shown as below:
[image]

When I did selecting, cell changed like below:

#### 1. Selected row No.1:

[image]

#### 2. Selected row No.2:

[image]

#### 3. Selected row No.3:

[image]

It seems that the height of cell before selected was `44`, when selected, it changed to `32`. They were overlapped one by one like cards, right? Weird!

### The main code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:15.0f]];
        UIView * seperateLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, cell.frame.size.height - 1.0f, 300.0f, 1.0f)];
        NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> %f", cell.frame.size.height);
        [seperateLine setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:seperateLine];
        [seperateLine release];
    }

    //...
}
```

I tried to check the `cell.frame.size.height`, and finally it was `44`. And then, I replace the line

```
UIView * seperateLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, cell.frame.size.height - 1.0f, 300.0f, 1.0f)];
```

to

```
UIView * seperateLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 31.0f, 300.0f, 1.0f)];
```

It worked as the first image shown above. But `the cell's height was still 44`, they(which we just cannot see totally) ware still overlapped. What I had done is just added a `separate line` at where `y` position is `32` but its total height is `44`.

---

So **what do you think about this? :?**

Comment: There's a reason why the default row height is 44 points: That's the approximate size of a human finger. If you make the rows smaller than that, I hope you don't expect the user to tap on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

According to apple's HIG the default tapable area is 44, so by default all control has 44 height.

you define new `UITableViewCell` inside

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

which is by default 44 and you change nothing in `UITableViewCell`'s frame and return it.

**Solution:**

try setting the frame size of the `UITableViewCell` i.e `cell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 32.0f)`

Comment: Mum, this should work! Thank you! And here's a new question: Why `NSLog(@"%@", cell.frame.size.height);` below `if (cell == nil) {...}` print as `NULL`, not `32`?

Comment: did you put NSLog() before setting frame?

Comment: Nope, I put it after setting. :?

Comment: You should put it after setting frame

Comment: Not that it matters anymore, but %@ assumes an object, whereas a height is an int, so you need %d

Comment: NSLog(@"height: %f", cell.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 2):

Please refer [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and look for `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method. Using which you can set height for each row. It can be fixed or can be dynamic as well as per your requirement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had implement this delegate method as well..and return value to 32.0f.