# UITableView strange layout iOS8 - UITableViewCellSeperatorView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a strange problem where the separator lines crawl onto the cells. The same row height is specified both in interface builder for the table and the cells (68 pixels). Is this an autolayout problem? This did not happen in iOS7

[image]

This happens after refreshing the table: only the bottom cell is broken. Anyone know why? Don't mind the change in color- the screenshots were taken at different times.

[image]

EDIT:

This is a problem pertaining to the UITableViewCellSeperatorView not lining up with the height of the cell defined in interface builder as well as the row height defined through code and through interface builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent two days on this so I hope this helps you out.

related questions:
[When I set the rowHeight for UITableView, shouldn't the height of cell changed as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489876/when-i-set-the-rowheight-for-uitableview-shouldnt-the-height-of-cell-changed-a)
      and
 [UITableView separator strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589899/uitableview-separator-strange-behavior)

After asking a lot of questions on freenode, maqr suggested it was an autolayout issue -- i checked for ambiguous constraints and there were none, using `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]`

Next I discovered that the gray line was the UITableViewCellSeparatorView using the view-hierarchy inspect tool in xcode 6.

Then I searched for how to fix this. The most straightforward way is to set the frame of your cell manually. This is crazy of course, but it works. Do it inside:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**Solution:**

try setting the frame size of the UITableViewCell i.e `cell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 32.0f)`

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/593709/adil-soomro

Comment: For me it seems you messed up something in cells or did not specify cell's rowHeight.

Comment: nope... did a lot of testing and this is the solution honestly.

Comment: it would be great if you could post _autolayoutTrace at least, because setting cell's frame manually is a really really bad idea.